# Build java application that uses opencv portable

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv, executable-jar

I want to create executable .jar file that *opencv* is embedded in the package. I mean that I can run it on another computer. Please, someone helps me???

I have this code in file `SimpleSample.java`:

```
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;

class SimpleSample {

  static{ System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME); }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Welcome to OpenCV " + Core.VERSION);
    Mat m = new Mat(5, 10, CvType.CV_8UC1, new Scalar(0));
    System.out.println("OpenCV Mat: " + m);
    Mat mr1 = m.row(1);
    mr1.setTo(new Scalar(1));
    Mat mc5 = m.col(5);
    mc5.setTo(new Scalar(5));
    System.out.println("OpenCV Mat data:\n" + m.dump());
  }
}
```

I try to run it after building with Ant, `build.xml`:

```
<project name="SimpleSample" basedir="." default="rebuild-run">
    <property name="src.dir"     value="src"/>
    <property name="lib.dir"     value="${ocvJarDir}"/>
    <path id="classpath"><fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar"/></path>
    <property name="build.dir"   value="build"/>
    <property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes"/>
    <property name="jar.dir"     value="${build.dir}/jar"/>
    <property name="main-class"  value="${ant.project.name}"/>
    <target name="clean"><delete dir="${build.dir}"/></target>
    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
        <javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" classpathref="classpath"/>
    </target>
    <target name="jar" depends="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
        <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>
    <target name="run" depends="jar">
        <java fork="true" classname="${main-class}">
            <sysproperty key="java.library.path" path="${ocvLibDir}"/>
            <classpath>
                <path refid="classpath"/>
                <path location="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar"/>
            </classpath>
        </java>
    </target>
    <target name="rebuild" depends="clean,jar"/>
    <target name="rebuild-run" depends="clean,run"/>
</project>
```

I got this exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/opencv/core/Core   at SimpleSample.(Unknown Source) Caused
>   by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.opencv.core.Core    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 1 more

Then I tried eclipse, and got this:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no
>   opencv_java300 in java.library.path   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864)  at
>   java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)  at
>   java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)    at
>   test.Test.(Test.java:10)  at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native
>   Method)   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)  at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:56)

What I have to do to generate jar file that works fine??? Thanks!!

Obs: I have built opencv as static library:

> cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to package static library with jar file, load that static library to a temperory file, and load you static library from that path.

Make a folder in resources named opencv and place `.dll` or `.dylib` files in respective folders.

```
public class LoadLibrary {
public static void loadOpenCV() {
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        File fileOut = null;
        String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");
        System.out.println(osName);

        if (osName.startsWith("Windows")) {
            int bitness = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model"));
            if (bitness == 32) {
                inputStream = LoadLibrary.class.getResourceAsStream("/opencv/windows/x86/opencv_java300.dll");
                fileOut = File.createTempFile("lib", ".dll");
            } else if (bitness == 64) {
                inputStream = LoadLibrary.class.getResourceAsStream("/opencv/windows/x64/opencv_java300.dll");
                fileOut = File.createTempFile("lib", ".dll");
            } else {
                inputStream = LoadLibrary.class.getResourceAsStream("/opencv/windows/x86/opencv_java300.dll");
                fileOut = File.createTempFile("lib", ".dll");
            }
        } else if (osName.equals("Mac OS X")) {
            inputStream = LoadLibrary.class.getResourceAsStream("/opencv/mac/libopencv_java300.dylib");
            fileOut = File.createTempFile("lib", ".dylib");
        }

        if (fileOut != null) {
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileOut);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;

            while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();
            System.load(fileOut.toString());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Change `Static { System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME); }` to `LoadLibrary.loadOpenCV();` in Main or before calling OpenCV functions.

And try to export your jar file from Eclipse. It will work just fine.

Comment: How should i do that?? Thanks

Comment: thanks, but i am working in linux, there is no dll, there is .a and .so file

Comment: Can you mention the names of .so and .a files?

Comment: http://imgur.com/bMPZK7M    all my .a and .so file, i did put these files in src of my project, these are in /src/opencv

Comment: The file you will be needing will be named "libopencv_java300.so", make subfolder in opencv directory in resources and put it their. In `loadLibrary()` function, make check for linux and load `libopencv_java300.so`  file.

Comment: `if (osName.equals("Linux")){
          inputStream = LoadLibrary.class.getResourceAsStream("/opencv/libopencv_java300.os");
          fileOut = File.createTempFile("lib", ".os");
         }`

Comment: i got java.lang.NullPointerException, in `while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0)`

Comment: `inputStream` will be null if it is unable to find file. Are you getting NullPointer while running from IDE or while running from .jar file?

Comment: I am running from IDE, eclipse

Comment: You will need to debug and check what is the value of `osName` and check if resources are being loaded correctly.
It is working on Mac and Windows on the application that I made.

Comment: i did, it is Linux, there is correct, it cant find the file opencv/libopencv_java300.os
`java.lang.NullPointerException
 at test.LoadLibrary.loadOpenCV(LoadLibrary.java:42)
 at test.Test.<clinit>(Test.java:10)`

Comment: There is no `.os` file, only `.so` file for Linux. First you need to change this `File.createTempFile("lib", ".os");`  to `File.createTempFile("lib", ".so");`
Secondly, place other files in you resource folder and try loading them, check if you are getting your resource folder correctly. This NullPointer will only occur when you are not getting your resource folder correctly.

Comment: Oh! it works in IDE, but i got warning `Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /tmp/lib6391393096712220801.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.`

Comment: and when i try .jar file, i got `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader can not access a member of class test.Test with modifiers "public static"
 at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:102)
 at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.slowCheckMemberAccess(AccessibleObject.java:296)
 at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:288)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:490)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)`

Comment: Well you got warning because you created a temp file from program and accessed it. Good practice will be to delete that temp file when exiting the program. 

And can you post the code that how are you calling LoadLibrary function from main?

Comment: `LoadLibrary.loadOpenCV();` is itself a static call. remove this line `  static{ LoadLibrary.loadOpenCV(); }
` and place only `LoadLibrary.loadOpenCV();`   as first line in main method.

Comment: Remove `Core.VERSION`

Comment: same exception, `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader can not access a member of class test.Test with modifiers "public static"`

Comment: Maybe you have some mis-configuration in eclipse, or maybe you may have more than one main calls. I can't be for sure. The exception you are getting, only occurs when you try to access a 'static' method of a class illegally. 
I would suggest that make a completely new project, Copy `loadOpenCV ` function and test that in by calling from main. I have tested it by calling from main method, by calling from other classes, by calling at the end, it didn't crash yet runs jar file, gives expected output and exits gracefully.