# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException - Eclipse with OpenCV

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv

When I run my below code I get the below error, but it worked before and I am not sure what Eclipse got and is not good anymore

**Error: Unable to initialize main class src.convolution
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/opencv/core/Mat**

```
package src;

import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

public class convolution {
   public static void main( String[] args ) {

      try {
         int kernelSize = 9;
         System.loadLibrary( Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME );

         Mat source = Imgcodecs.imread("C:/Users/B & B/Desktop/ProcIMG/grayscale.jpg", Imgcodecs.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
         Mat destination = new Mat(source.rows(),source.cols(),source.type());

         Mat kernel = new Mat(kernelSize,kernelSize, CvType.CV_32F){
            {
               put(0,0,-3);
               put(0,1,-3);
               put(0,2,-3);

               put(1,0-3);
               put(1,1,0);
               put(1,2,-3);

               put(2,0,5);
               put(2,1,5);
               put(2,2,5);
            }
         };       

         Imgproc.filter2D(source, destination, -1, kernel);
         Imgcodecs.imwrite("C:/Users/B & B/Desktop/ProcIMG/output.jpg", destination);

      } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you refer this one
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33198101/build-java-application-that-uses-opencv-portable

Comment: I have tried a lot of the "solutions" in there Deepak Jain, unfortunately none worked.

Answer (score 0):

It could be .classpath issue. Try following steps

- Delete Project from Eclipse **don't delete content from disk**.
- remove .classpath and .project files
- re-import project in Eclipse

Comment: Thank you Swarit Agarwal, I did what you said, but the error persists. No clue how to fix this.

Comment: Can you check with *Project > Build Project* is enabled. BTW Is this a maven based project?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, maybe you have already found your answer but as it is the first result of my web research I want to offer a solution to the others :

Just add the opencv_xxx.jar to the project classpath as external class. and it will work fine. (in Menu project -> properties -> java build path -> libraries tab -> classpath-> add  external class folder button)

Hope it help many of you